# Using Vim as external editor using only one instance

Tags: command-line, scripts, games, vim, gvim

I'm playing a game that has a scripting language. It has a button to open the scripts in external editor. You can set the command that will trigger the editor from within the game's interface.

`/usr/bin/X11/gvim` opens the scripts in gvim

now what I would like to know is, if it's doable, to open the scripts in terminal's vim and if instead of opening a new one each time to add tabs to the existing instance. What would be a command to do that?

the way of adding tabs is `:tabe filename` or from terminal for multiple documents

`vim -p file1, file2`

I guess there are more that I don't know, I hope this is doable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with vim's server mode. Start a vim-server with:

```
vim --servername somename
```

Now you can send commands to it with `--remote`, `--remote-send` and others.

To achieve what you want, start a server with a known name, send the `:tabe` commands with:

```
vim --servername somename --remote-send ':tabe filename<cr>'
```

**Note** the same commands work for gvim. If this should work from within another program, you need to start the vim-server prior to any `--remote-send` commands. The edit command within the program should then be: `vim --servername somename --remote-send ':tabe %s<cr>'`, assuming `%s` is replaced by the filename to edit.

Comment: Ty for your answer, I def learned something from that. But it doesn't seem to work. The problem is that I don't actually know how that external editor command works. E.g why wouldn't open vim in terminal? Even a single instance, it just wont do it. But it will open gvim. This is not kewl. Plus I don't know if it can accept command line arguments. This really bothers me, multiple windows are never good.

Comment: @DeusDeceit: IIUYC, you should first start the vim-server outside the program that will call `vim --remote-send`. See the added note above.